American high school students hating a cruel teacher
I am looking for a TV series that was taking place in an American high school. I was watching this in 2003, so it must have been published before that. At least in the episodes I remember, the plot was centered around one class of students, who had a middle-aged female teacher whom they hated, and who hated them. I think the name of the teacher was "Class", but this is obviously difficult to Google.
In one episode, there was a tree in front of the school, that had sentimental value to some student couple. It was to be felled, so the couple climbed in the tree. Their teacher ordered Air Force to bomb the tree with DDT, which they did. I don't remember how the episode continued after that.
In another episode, the class offers their teacher some poisoned drink, which is supposed to cause diarrhea. She refuses to drink it but then immediately falls unconsious and the class is accused for poisoning her. I think this was caused by some third party, which used voodoo against the teacher. The students think the teacher is dead, but later one of the students observes her farting and remarks "dead people don't fart". The teacher ends up in the autopsy, and is consious (she is under voodoo spell), even though the doctors think she is dead. During the operation, doctors remark "if she was still alive, this would hurt a lot", and "she is a medical miracle; she doesn't have a heart".

Funny enough, dead people do fart.

You're looking for the Ryan Murphy show Popular that ran on the WB in 1999-2001.

Two girls who despise each other, due to being on opposite sides of the "popularity fence", are forced together upon learning that their parents are getting married.

The evil teacher is Ms. Glass and the episodes you've described are "Timber!" (the season 2 opener where 2 students try to save a tree and Ms. Glass tries to take it down by, among other methods, spraying them with chemicals from a helicopter) and "Two Weddings and a Funeral" (the musical season 1 finale where the students try to poison Ms. Glass and she apparently dies), respectively. Murphy later reused some of its themes and characters on Glee. Here are the opening credits:



